# how to fetch colums data from two table using mysql with php using where

Tags: php, mysql

I have two Table `ownership_profile` and `socity_unit`.

**Query For table1:** `select * from ownership_profile where SID='$id'`

**Query For Table2:** `select * from socity_unit where socity_id='$sid'`

I have to join with one query, but i don't have idea how to do it.

This is my Php code but gives error:

```
<!-----------------Table For User Names-------------------------------------->      
<table border="1"  align="center">
        <tr>
            <th>Unit No</th>
            <th>Member Name</th>
            <th>Wing</th>
            <th>Unit</th>
        </tr>
    <?php
    if(isset($_GET['submit']))
    {
    $sql = "select * from ownership_profile o inner join society_unit s on o.sid = s.society_id where o.sid = '$sid' ";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    $i=1;
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    ?>



        <?php
    $name = $row['NAME'];
    $unitid = $row['UNIT_ID'];
    $sid = $row['SID'];
    $wings = $row['wings'];
    $unit_no = $row['unit_no'];
    {
    ?>  

    <!--User Submit Result-->
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $unitid; ?></td> 
            <td><?php echo $name; ?></td>   
            <td><?php echo $wings; ?></td>  
            <td><?php echo $unit_no; ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php }?>
    <?php
    //echo "<br>";
    $i++;
    }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Show your table structure and show what you have tried? Did you tried to use **JOIN** atleast once

Comment: So whats the error you were getting over here and from where you got `$sid`

Answer (score 0):

`inner join` is what you want.

```
select *
  from ownership_profile o
    inner join society_unit s
      on o.sid = s.society_id
  where o.sid = '$sid'
```

This assumes that 'sid' and 'society_id' are the relationship identifiers.

Comment: exactly the same way as you would retrieve the results for just one of the queries.

Comment: i edited my query ... with php codes... plz solve this

Comment: well you spelt it `socity_unit` i spelt it `society_unit`, that probably doesn't help. you need to make a little effort, and show the errors. try printing the query out and then running it manually

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2
ON table1.column_name=table2.column_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from ownership_profile o inner join socity_unit s on o.SID = s.socity_id where o.SID = '$SOCIETY_ID'
```

This query working fine but...... its generate dublicate entry from table